# WebAPI OData v4 custom action without parameters can't be routed with error "No routing convention was found..."

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have very simple OData controller that successfully process standard actions (at least GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods are working). I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions) and added simple bound action. The method has parameters argument, but actually it does not required the parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Close([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters) {
  return Ok();
}
```

I have defined this action in OData EDM configuration as following:

```
builder.EntitySet<Ticket>("tickets");
builder.EntityType<Ticket>().Action("Close");
```

I am trying to call action from Postman:

```
POST /odata/tickets(2)/Default.Close HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50477
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: eef4c1f6-8c7f-f5eb-c22d-4397f3bda170
```

But receives the error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50477/odata/tickets(2)/default.close'.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.",
      "type": "",
      "stacktrace": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I have read the whole internet and all related articles on SO but can't fix this issue. Please help me because I have no any fresh idea how to fight this.

Comment: what's your WebAPI/OData version, and can you share your  metadata, I still can't repro your issue.

Comment: OData v4, WebApi 2.2. PLease look at metadata: http://pastebin.com/MuPzFPxe

Comment: what is the JSON that you are sending to the controller ?

Comment: I found the reason of error - the incorrect rewrite rule. When I have disabled all rewrite rules all test are passed.

Answer (score 0):

My controller:

```
public class TicketsController : ODataController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Close([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

My request:

```
        string requestUri = "http://localhost/odata/tickets(2)/Default.Close";

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
        request.Content = new StringContent("",
                                Encoding.UTF8,
                                "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = _client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

Or remove the `ODataActionParameters parameters` in the close method and call with:

```
        string requestUri = "http://localhost/odata/tickets(2)/Default.Close";

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
        HttpResponseMessage response = _client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

My EdmModel is use your model.

Comment: Thank you for you attempt but... Seems that all listed above things are identical but something else has negative effect. I still see "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50477/odata/tickets(2)/default.close'." I don't know where to look.